# Croping whitespace (transparancy) from all pngs in office file (with screen-recording)

Tags: microsoft-office

I run a small open souce assistive technology project ([github](https://github.com/joereddington/azulejoe) link) that processes templates that users create in PowerPoint. The code dosen't deal gracefully with the case where transparency makes the image larger than the cell.

In effect, I have a PowerPoint document that contains a great many png images.  Many of there images are actually small images with a large 'transparent' areas around them.

I'd like to be able to crop these images so their transparent bounding box was as small as possible with cropping and of the visible parts. Can this be done?

Here's a screen recording showing what I'm having to do for each image individually.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2L-DtEZaxxM

Comment: Are you talking about cropping (modifying) the actual image or simply making the "window on the image" tighter?  Are you looking for some automated way to do them all at once?

Comment: @fixer1234 Either or both :)